# Quick navigation by function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there any plug-in for Flash that allows you to open a list of code functions and a quick transition to the function?

It is not very convenient in its large code to look for functions.

Comment: Ever heard of ctrl+f?

Comment: And organised project structure

Answer (score 0):

Write all your code in [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/).

You'll be able to see all your functions in a navigation panel, and even select them from a dropdown menu.

Comment: And how to use the FLASH library? Export clip animation to SWC?

Comment: Well that depends. You can actually just make a Flash IDE project in FlashDevelop, and then writing code in FlashDevelop isn't much different from writing it in Flash, and you can even press a hotkey in FlashDevelop to switch over to the IDE and automatically test your project. On the other hand you can build swf projects entirely in FlashDevelop using a Flex SDK, and in that case you'd want to put any vector assets you need in a SWC.